# How to cache user.groups in a request so db isn't hit every time you call request.user.groups.all()?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm using Django with Django REST and have a user permission system based on user groups. As a result I have to check assigned user groups a few times inside views to see if a user belongs to a certain group using  `request.user.groups.all()`. It works but every such call results in an extra query to db to retrieve groups.

I wish I could override some method that pulls a user from a db during authentication before attaching it to a request, so I can add something like

```
User.objects.get(pk=userid).prefetch_related('groups')
```

so no extra calls would be made whenever I access groups further down.

Comment: Why don't you do the groups query once and pass that around?

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there a good place to do such a query, right after the request object is formed and before it is used anywhere? I need it in many places (like inside view's `get_queryset()`, inside serializers and inside other random methods), the order is not really straight forward and I don't have control over what parameters are passed around as many of those are some internal Django or DRF classes.

Answer (score 0):

So, as you mentioned in your question, you can create your custom django backend class and override `get_user` from `django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend`. It will look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as DjangoGroup
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

UserModel = get_user_model()


class BackendWithPrefetchedUser(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = (
                UserModel._default_manager.filter(pk=user_id)
                .prefetch_related("groups")
            )[0]
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

And then create varible `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ["your_app.backends.BackendWithPrefetchedUser"]` in your project settings