# How do you prefetch django user groups for permissions checks

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a class that has permissions are checked over and over.  Each time the request user's groups are re-queried from the database instead of caching them making thing really slow.  How can I prefetch or cache the groups in the request user?

```
class Object(models.Model):
    ...
    def has_object_read_permission(self, request):
        if ('test' not in request.user.groups.all()):
             return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the profile caching method in this answer.

[How to cache user.groups in a request so db isn't hit every time you call request.user.groups.all()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236677/how-to-cache-user-groups-in-a-request-so-db-isnt-hit-every-time-you-call-reques)

here is the code, there is a bug fix to add "not" to the if statement

```
class User(...):
    @property
    def cached_groups(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_cached_groups'):
            self._cached_groups = list(self.groups.all())
        return self._cached_groups
```

Comment: You might want to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to optimise this would be with a cache like redis or memcached.

I've used [django-cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) with success for database query caching.  It works quite seamlessly with only a little bit of configuration.

If you look at the [setup](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops#setup) section you'll notice you can target specific models for caching in the settings:

```
CACHEOPS_DEFAULTS = {
    'timeout': 60*60
}
CACHEOPS = {
    'auth.user': {'ops': 'get', 'timeout': 60*15},
    'auth.*': {'ops': ('fetch', 'get')},
    'auth.permission': {'ops': 'all'},
    '*.*': {},
}
```

This way you could start by caching your users and group queries and later optimize other models too if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  While it looks nice, I have an ecosystem that would require multiple installations of redis or memcached.  The implementation is not a lot of data so if I can stay in memory I would try to pick that first.

Comment: Binding `*.*` is discouraged since cacheops 4.0.1, since it prevents fast path deletes and simply creates useless signal handlers.

Comment: This still hits the network for every request, and is probably not much faster than the simple database query. Instead I would make sure to only request these objects once per request by using prefetch_related.